# trigger for insert to check sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sum

I'm trying to create a trigger to check that the sum of inserts of three different wood types should sum as 10 (10 represent 100%) on a specific 'work area' in a table called SpaceMixes. 'Percentage' is the column where the percentage of a wood type are stored in a specific work space (wood types are named 'H', 'P' or 'F').

These work spaces are defined by their primary key of the combination (AreaNr, SpaceNr), even though the entire PK for SpaceMixes are (AreaNr, SpaceNr, WoodType). The trigger below checks that the sum can only be 10 in one work space, but the problem is that the first value also must be 10 with this code. But I would like to be able to insert like "2+5+3" for a work space, and it should not allow like 2+5+5, since that would transcend the sum of 10 in total for that work space (see desired result).

The current trigger I use:

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER trg_Sum ON SpaceMixes
FOR INSERT AS

DECLARE @sum INT

SELECT @sum = sum(SpaceMixes.Percentage)
FROM inserted, SpaceMixes
WHERE inserted.AreaNr = SpaceMixes.AreaNr AND inserted.SpaceNr = SpaceMixes.SpaceNr
GROUP BY inserted.AreaNr

IF NOT (@sum = 10)

BEGIN
RAISERROR ('The sum of the percentages must be 10 for each work space!',16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

DESIRED RESULT:
The first two inserts below should work just fine, but I would like the trigger to be activated on the third one, since the percentage '5' would transcend the sum of 10 (5+3+5=13) for the work space (2, 3). I other words, the third insert should only be allowed if the given percentage was 2 instead of 5.

```sql
INSERT INTO SpaceMixes VALUES (2, 3, 'P', 5)
INSERT INTO SpaceMixes VALUES (2, 3, 'F', 3)
INSERT INTO SpaceMixes VALUES (2, 3, 'H', 5)
```

Does someone know how to fix this trigger to make this sum work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should include a `CHECK` constaint in `SpaceMixes` table so as to ensure that no single record ever exceeds the maximum percentage value:

```
ALTER TABLE SpaceMixes ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Percentage CHECK  ( [Percentage] <=10 )
```

This trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Sums] ON [dbo].[SpaceMixes]
   AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS  

-- First check Work spaces having only two records (not yet complete).
-- These should have a percentage not greater than 10, allowing for the insertion of
-- the last work space member.
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 NULL
    FROM (
       SELECT SUM(Percentage) AS TotalPercentage
       FROM SpaceMixes
       WHERE AreaNr = (SELECT AreaNr FROM inserted) AND 
             SpaceNr = (SELECT SpaceNr FROM inserted) 
       GROUP BY AreaNr, SpaceNr
       HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) t
   WHERE t.TotalPercentage > 10 
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('The sum of the percentages cannot be greater than 10 for any sub-workspace!',16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END

-- Now check Work spaces having exactly three records (i.e. complete workspace).  
-- These should have a total percentage equal to 10.
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT TOP 1 NULL
   FROM (SELECT SUM(Percentage) AS TotalPercentage
         FROM SpaceMixes
         WHERE AreaNr = (SELECT AreaNr FROM inserted) AND 
               SpaceNr = (SELECT SpaceNr FROM inserted) 
         GROUP BY AreaNr, SpaceNr
         HAVING COUNT(*) = 3) t
   WHERE t.TotalPercentage <> 10    
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('The sum of the percentages must be 10 for each work space!',16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

should do the job. Please note that apart from `INSERT` you should define the trigger also for `UPDATE`.

Having inserted these two records:

```
INSERT INTO SpaceMixes VALUES (2, 3, 'P', 5)
INSERT INTO SpaceMixes VALUES (2, 3, 'F', 3)
```

both of the following `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries raise an error:

```
INSERT INTO SpaceMixes VALUES (2, 3, 'H', 5) -- SUM = 13
INSERT INTO SpaceMixes VALUES (2, 3, 'H', 1) -- SUM = 9

-- UPDATE SpaceMixes after inserting a percentage of 2 for WOOD TYPE = 'H'
UPDATE SpaceMixes
SET Percentage = 6
WHERE AreaNr = 2 AND SpaceNr =3 And WoodType = 'F'
```

Comment: @eqinna It is just a quick way to denote that at least one record is returned from the query. Just do a `SELECT TOP 1 NULL FROM SpaceMixes` when SpaceMixes contains at least one record and when SpaceMixes is empty and you will see.

Comment: @eqinna It is relatively easy to fix this.

Comment: @eqinna `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` ensures that only **complete** workspaces will be checked

Comment: @eqinna Have you checked my latest update? You need both the `CHECK` constraint and the secondary `IF EXISTS` statemement so that your trigger is complete.

Comment: I've tried it several times now, and it seems to work. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is a good data modeling rule to avoid spreading data integrity requirements across different rows of the same table if at all possible. As you see, it creates problems enforcing the constraints.

Here's a tradeoff you may want to consider. You could have all three values on the same row:

```
create table SpaceMixes(
  AreaNr    int not null,
  SpaceNr   int not null,
  P_Wood    int,
  F_Wood    int,
  H_Wood    int,
  ...
  constraint PK_SpaceMixes primary key( AreaNr, SpaceNr ),
  constraint CK_Exactly10Required check( IsNull( P_Wood + F_Wood + H_Wood, 10 ) = 10 ),
  constraint CK_Total10Exceeded check( IsNull( P_Wood, 0 ) + IsNull( F_Wood, 0 ) + IsNull( H_Wood, 0 ) <= 10 ),
);
```

The advantage is that most of what you want is achievable through normal check constraints. The CK_Exactly10Required constraint will enforce the rule that if all three fields have a value, the total must equal 10. The CK_Total10Exceeded constraint will enforce the rule that no matter how many values are defined, the total cannot exceed 10. You can add other constraints (e.g. no value may be negative) as desired to refine the checking. No triggers needed -- for this purpose, anyway.

The tradeoff is that you would have to add a new field instead of a new row in order to handle a fourth type of wood. How critical that is would depend on the probability that such a situation would occur.

**Edit**: Even if you don't want to or can't denormalize, I thought I may as well submit my own trigger for your consideration. You don't really need a separate check constraint to verify each value is 10 or less as the trigger will also catch that condition. I would recommend a check constraint to catch negative values. This can also be placed in the trigger, but checks should be made at as low a level as possible.

On to the trigger. This will work for Inserts *and* Updates. There is no need for a Delete trigger as there is no delete action that will end up with an invalid amount. As you can see in the query, it just verifies that for three entries the total must be exactly 10 otherwise it must be ten or less. Just check for any deviation and raise an error if found.

```
create trigger SpaceMixes_IU
on SpaceMixes
after insert, update as
declare
    @Result int;

with
KeyList as(
    select  distinct AreaNr, SpaceNr
    from    inserted
)
select  @Result = case when Count( * ) = 3
            then case Sum( sm.Percentage ) when 10 then 0 else 1 end
        else case when Sum( sm.Percentage ) <= 10 then 0 else 1 end
        end
from    SpaceMixes  sm
join    KeyList     kl
    on  kl.AreaNr   = sm.AreaNr
    and kl.SpaceNr  = sm.SpaceNr
group by sm.AreaNr, sm.SpaceNr;

if @Result > 0 begin
    Rollback;
    RaisError( 'Workspace percentages not valid!', 16, 0 );
end;
```

Comment: The wood types 'P', 'F' and 'H' should not be common attributes in the table SpaceMixes. This is to reduce redundancy. Therefore it is better to store the wood types in a separate table, like I do now, and use them as a part of the primary key as well as foreign keys in the table SpiceMixes.

Comment: I don't know if I would say "should not be..." One may (and people often do) make valid arguments either way. However, I realized you may not want or be able to go that route which is why I offered a trigger also.

Comment: Anyway, I should add that it was nice of you taking the time offering a solution. :)